# Getting no value from JSON array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, jsonexception

I have a weird problem and I hope that you can help me with it..

The problem is as follows:
I have created a javacode to resolve a query from JSON but I can't parse it to a String... I also tried to get the String 0, but that also does not work.

Underneath, the code from Java:

```
JSONArray json_data = new JSONArray(result);
           for (int i = 0; i < json_data.length(); i++) {
                code = json_data.getJSONObject(i).getInt("code");
                pictureID = json_data.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "Picture_ID");
                System.out.println(code);
                System.out.println(pictureID);
            }
```

This is the response I get from JSON:

```
[{"code":1}][{"Picture_ID":"74","0":"74"}]
```

But this is the error I get from the catch clause:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for Picture_ID
```

Again, Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: but code an Picture_ID seem to be in different object

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I don't understand.

Comment: `[{"code":1}][{"Picture_ID":"74","0":"74"}]` is not valid json

Comment: I find it a bit offensive that you say that somebody does not know what he is talking about, when someone is learning about it Blackbelt... Thanks Selvin, I will try to make a valid JSON response than.

Comment: your json is invalid try checking it online in sites like jsonlint.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you check key value "Picture_ID" is correct, if it correct try with this code...

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) {

JSONObject obj = innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);

String projNum = obj.optString("code"); 
String projName = obj.optString("Picture_ID"); 
// and use both values. 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting no value for Picture_ID anymore... But how can I get the value from the JSON response if the key is incorrect?

Comment: This is valid json....       {
   "phoneNumber": [
      {
         "type": "work",
         "num": "11111"
      },
      {
         "type": "home",
         "num": "2222"
      }
   ],
   "address": {
      "state": "World",
      "address": "infinite space, 000",
      "city": "Android city"
   },
   "surname": "Swa",
   "name": "Android"
}